# How does a cell discharge their voltage?

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, voltage, batteries, electrochemistry

I'm posting this question because I haven't been able to find any sources on the internet to make sense of. The statement I am working with is as follows:

> The terminal potential difference of a typical
> practical electric cell loses its initial value quickly, has a stable and constant
> value for most of its lifetime, followed by a rapid decrease to zero as the cell
> discharges completely.

Could someone try to explain this very brief explanation?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/696554/195949

Comment: I think that the reason why you are not getting answers is that the question (as to why the potential difference falls rapidly by a small amount at first before stabilising) is more difficult and requires more specialist knowledge than you might have imagined.

Comment: @PhilipWood I think so too. Seeing as I am by no means a specialist, I think I'll settle at the rudimentary explanation I have.

Answer (score 1):

The open circuit cell voltage is related to the (near to) equilibrium potentials at both electrodes inside the cell, at which there are ongoing (nearly) zero net chemical redox reactions. That means the reversible redox reactions (separate ones at each electrode) are ongoing both directions at the same rate. It does not mean the cell equilibrium, which would happen at fully discharged cell.

Closing the circuit causes current between electrodes at different potentials. Electrode potentials are this way externally forced to shift to each other, what causes net chemical reactions at the electrodes.

- The potential of more negative anode increases, what causes chemical oxidation outruns reduction, releasing electrons to the circuit.
- The potential of more positive cathode decreases, what causes chemical reduction outruns oxidation, capturing electrons from the circuit.

There is established such a cell on-load voltage at which is managed a steady state due the same rates of:

- releasing electrons at the anode
- passing electrons through the circuit
- capturing electrons at cathode

When some of electroactive cell components are near exhausted, the cell voltage starts to drop progressively to adapt the current to the ceasing ability of the cell to release or capture electrons.

Answer (score 0):

It has been my experience that the open circuit voltage (measured with a digital meter) of a new (alkaline) cell is about 1.68 volts.  Under load, the chemical reaction within the cell cannot keep up with the demand and the voltage drops by an amount that tends to be proportional to the load. That behavior is often modeled by assuming that the cell has an “internal resistance”. When the load is removed, the voltage goes back up, but over the lifetime of the cell, as the density of energy containing chemicals decreases, the voltage of the cell will gradually decrease. Some devices will not function well with cells that show an open circuit voltage of 1.5 volts.   Others (like TV remotes) may continue to function down to 1.3 volts. Since the cells are normally replaced when the device malfunctions, one rarely sees a cell that shows no voltage.